# Creating a stream of booleans from a boolean array?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

How do I create a stream of booleans from a boolean array?

Something like:

```
Arrays.stream(new boolean[] { true, false })
```

Java 8 provides stream methods for `int[]`, `double[]`, `long[]` etc. but not for `boolean[]`.